# Compare dialog does not show differences

Tags: svn, eclipse, version-control, comparison

In Eclipse, my Compare dialog does not show differences between files, if I compare two folders or revisions.
For example the text file `ant` (without an extension) is not compared well.

There are no differences shown but the file is listed in the folder structure above.

[image: Compare Dialog]

What could be the reason for this behaviour? Is there something wrong with the settings or with this ant file?

It makes the directory compare completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the only thing that changed between the two revisions is whitespace and you have configured the compare feature to ignore whitespace?

If it's not that, then it's probably just the svn plugin having some sort of hiccup (it's somewhat buggy); maybe try closing and reopening the project and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It was not the SVN plugin, but the white space.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Ganymede (3.4.0).

What confuses me is: You write that you compare two folders but your screenshot looks as if you compare different revisions of the same file. There is *Local* and *Rev:-1* where plain file paths should be.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, I compared two revisions. -- My problem with "Show Content Comparison" is that it says "no differences" even if there are differences.

Comment: Are you sure you are not comparing identical files because the Local file is identical to Rev:-1? Is there a situation where compare works as expected or does this happen all the time with all files?

Comment: The problem is that it is identical. But Eclipse does show it in the upper file tree. That is not normal if the files are equal.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I have this effect also sometimes. It always helped to select the file and Refresh(F5) it. In fact I have to do Refresh quite often when I work with Eclipse. Maybe you also have to resynchronize with the repository.